# Cannot resolve method setToNow() on Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I am getting an error Cannot resolve method **setToNow()**, **getJulianDay** on Android Studio. I think i have imported the correct Classes.

[image]

**Imports**

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Time;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
```

---

```
Time dayTime = new Time();
dayTime.setToNow();
int julianStartDay = Time.getJulianDay(System.currentTimeMillis(), dayTime.gmtoff);
```

Comment: import `android.text.format.Time` instead of `java.sql.Time`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `setToNow()` in `java.sql.Time` you need to use `android.text.format.Time`.

But be careful because it is deprecated

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html
>
> This class was deprecated in API level 22.
> Use GregorianCalendar instead.